# Python Pandas: Get 2 set of random samples per group

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame say this:

```
   user  value
0     a      1
1     a      2
2     a      3
3     a      4
4     a      5
5     b      6
6     b      7
7     b      8
8     b      9
9     b     10
10    c     11
11    c     12
12    c     13
13    c     14
14    c     15
```

Now I want to group by user, and create two mutually exclusive random samples out of it e.g

Set1 with 1 samples per group:

```
   user  value
3     a      4
9     b     10
13    c     14
```

Set2 with 2 samples per group:

```
   user  value
0     a      1
1     a      2
5     b      6
6     b      7
10    c     11
11    c     12
```

So far i'v tried this:

```
u = np.array(['a','b','c'])
u = np.repeat(u,5)
df = pd.DataFrame({'user':u,'value':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]})

set1  = df.groupby(['user']).tail(1)
set2  = df.groupby(['user']).head(2)
```

But these are not random samples, and i would like them to be mutually exclusive. Any ideas?

PS. Each group always has at least 3 elements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can randomly select 3 records for each user:

```
a = df.groupby("user")["value"].apply(lambda x: x.sample(3))

a
Out[27]: 
user    
a     3      4
      0      1
      2      3
b     5      6
      7      8
      6      7
c     14    15
      10    11
      13    14
dtype: int64
```

And assign first one to the first set, the remaining two to the second set:

```
a.groupby(level=0).head(1)
Out[28]: 
user    
a     3      4
b     5      6
c     14    15
dtype: int64

a.groupby(level=0).tail(2)
Out[29]: 
user    
a     0      1
      2      3
b     7      8
      6      7
c     10    11
      13    14
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Yeah I like this better than my answer, much more clean although I think apply is unnecessary. I think you could just sample the whole DataFrame and do the groupings as usual: `df.sample(len(df)).groupby('user').head(1)`.

Comment: Yeah, `df.sample(len(df))` is probably doing the same thing under the hood (random permutation of the index). But I thought the original dataframe might be large so creating another dataframe of same lenght might not be optimal.

Answer (score 2):

This maybe a bit naive but all I did was reindex the DataFrame with a random permutation of the length of the DataFrame and reset the index. After that I take the head and tail as you did with your original code, seems to work. This could probably be made into a function:

```
a = np.arange(len(df))
np.random.shuffle(a)
df = df.reindex(a).reset_index()

set1  = df.groupby(['user']).tail(1)
>>> 
    index user  value
12      9    b     10
13     10    c     11
14      1    a      2

set2  = df.groupby(['user']).head(2)
>>>
   index user  value
0      6    b      7
1      2    a      3
2      5    b      6
3     13    c     14
4      3    a      4
6     12    c     13
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

There is likely a better solution but what about just randomizing your data before grouping and then taking the tail and head per group? You could take a set of your indices, take a random permutation of it and use that to create a new scrambled dataframe, then do your current procedure.